# Using Braillie Font in TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, moodle

I am interested to know how we can use braillie fonts in TinyMCE editor. Currently, I want to integrate this capability in Moodle which uses TinyMCE as its default editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could add a font to tinymce was to edit the core code.

First Copy your font files to `/theme/yourtheme/fonts/`

Create a css file for your fonts in `/theme/yourtheme/style/fonts.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'yourfont';
    src:url('/theme/yourtheme/fonts/yourfont.eot') format('eot'),
        url('/theme/yourtheme/fonts/yourfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/theme/yourtheme/fonts/yourfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/theme/yourtheme/fonts/yourfont.svg#yourfont') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

You'll also need to copy the @font-face above into `/theme/yourtheme/style/custom.css` so the font is displayed correctly.

Edit `/lib/editor/tinymce/lib.php` and add these 2 lines to `function get_init_params()` after the line  `$fontselectlist = empty($config->fontselectlist) ? '' : $config->fontselectlist;` (this is in Moodle 2.5)

```
    $contentcss .= ', /theme/yourtheme/style/fonts.css';
    $fontselectlist .= ';Your font=yourfont';
```

Purge the cache `/admin/purgecaches.php` refresh the browser and the font should be there now.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your reply. I tried the steps. In the editor, It also shows in the dropdown, but doesn't work when typing.